# Auto-populate Sharepoint list based on most recent list item in another

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, calculated-column

Can anyone help? I want to be able to auto populate a field within a SharPoint list based on the most up-to-date field within another list.

.

List Details

**Projects List** - List of projects.

Fields inc. *Project ID, Most Recent Comments, Status* etc.

**Project Comments list** - List of Project Comments linked to Project List by *Project ID*.

Fields inc. *Project ID, Subject, Comments, Created Date* etc.

.

Therefore the *'Most Recent Comments'* field in the Projects List always has the latest comment.

I know I can either use a workflow or a calculated field but not sure how to start it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Luke

Comment: Just to note that I am currently using Sharepoint 2010 Foundation.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution was a lot easier than first thought.

I just created a Reusable workflow in SPD running an update event handler which triggers upon new or any changes made to my Comments list.

Thanks for your contributions regardless guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some javascript to query Comment list to find the most recent comment and push that value into the Project list form field. [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) helps with a lot of these things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemAdding event handler to autopopulate the field in the list.